# Can I use CCLabelTTF instead of UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uilabel

I want to draw **highlight** to `UILabel` and to control **line-space** of `UILabel`.

But, It's not easy. So, I had known about '`CCLabelTTF`' through googling.

Question: Could I realize highlight and line-space with `CCLabelTTF` of cocos2d instead of `UILabel` in View-based application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Javy said it for Cocos2D only, but you can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Which will accept a [`NSAttributedString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html), in which you can set a part of the string to have a different background color.

Comment: Wow! Thanks!! This is what I want. re-Thanks!

Comment: CCLabelTTF class is not available in android?

Comment: @Dhrupal this question is about iOS development. You comment makes not sense.

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication. No its for android development. Actually cocos2d's functionality in android and ios is same, but i am not able to use custom font.

Comment: Then start a new question for your problem, you are not suppost to use the comments to ask questions. Since you problem has it own scope be sure to add the relative tags,

Answer (score 0):

CCLabelTTF is for Cocos2d applications only.  It does not work with standard UIKit applications.

Comment: Thanks your kind advice!! ^___^